# Laravel Eloquent query scope with join that uses DB::raw

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a query scope from a L5.1 app that is not working on L5.7.  The scope adds a simple join with a DB::raw statement like so:

```php
    public function scopeLatest($query)
    {
        return $query->join(DB::raw('(SELECT patient_id, MAX(created_at) created_at FROM referral_reports GROUP BY patient_id) r2'), function ($join) {
                            $join->on('referral_reports.patient_id', '=', 'r2.patient_id');
                            $join->on('referral_reports.created_at', '=', 'r2.created_at');
                            });
    }
```

Using this scope on L5.1 worked great, but in 5.7, the entire join is omitted from the query and no error is thrown.  I had to use DB::enableQueryLog() on both apps to see that the resulting queries were different.

Any idea why this isn't working in 5.7?

Here is an example of using this scope via a static method on the model:

```
        $entries = self::inStudies($studies)
                       ->calltime($startDate, $endDate)
                       ->latest()
                       ->omitdeleted()
                       ->get();
```

inStudies, calltime, latest, omitdeleted are all query scopes.

Comment: Please, add an example of code that utilizes this scope.

Comment: @Styx see above static method on the eloquent model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scope doesn't work because it conflicts with `latest` method. Just rename this scope and it will work.

`latest`/`oldest` methods have been [added in Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: works like a champ again, thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score -1):

Did you add use DB; on top?

Try these

```
public function scopeLatest($query){

return $query->join('referral_reports.patient_id', '=', 'r2.patient_id')

    ->join('referral_reports.created_at', '=', 'r2.created_at')

    ->select(DB::raw('SELECT patient_id, created_at) r2'));
}
```

Normally i would run the group by from controller

Model::latest()->max('created_at')->groupBy('patient_id')

Comment: yes use DB is there.  I tried your scope, it doesn't work.  In both cases (my scope and yours), the join statement is not included in the final resulting query.

Comment: I would be helpful if you provide the error message,Thanks.